# How to export all dataframes made by group_split

Tags: r, export, tibble

I am doing some text analysis in R Studio, and as part of this analysis I have split my data frame into various tibbles, split by a column in my data called "topic". This has worked successfully.

All I need to do now is find some way to export each of those tibbles into a csv, or xlxs or even html - anything that will let me look through them properly.

Has anyone got any solutions for this? Feels like it should be something easy to do but in my research it is not.

[A screenshot of the tibbles I am trying to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzNNs.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `map` or `lapply` to write each dataframe to a csv. However, `group_split` does not give names to the list. To get proper names of the csv you can use `split` and `imap` together.

For example, with `iris` dataset -

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  imap(~write_csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv')))
```

This creates 3 csvs named `virginia.csv`, `versicolor.csv` and `setosa.csv` in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a `for() loop` try this. You could probably find a better way to name the list items, but this works.

```
my_list <- mtcars %>%
  group_split(gear)

names(my_list) <- 1:length(my_list)


for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
  write_csv(my_list[[i]], file = paste0(names(my_list)[i], ".csv"))
}
```